# RSpec - Testing that an active record association is set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2, rspec-rails

I'm having trouble testing the following. When creating an object a status of "Pending" is assigned. The status is actually an active record association. So it looks like this

```
def object
  belongs_to :object_status
end

def object_status
  has_many :objects

  def self.pending
    find_by_name('pending')
  end
end
```

Then in the controller create it does this

```
@object = Object.new(params[:object])
@object.object_status = ObjectStatus.pending
@object.save
```

In RSpec I want to test to make sure that the object has a status of pending so I'm doing this in my objects_controller_spec:

```
post :create, :object => @attr # I'm using pre-defined attributes
p = Object.last
p.object_status_id.should eq(Factory(:object_status_pending).id)
```

The RSpec test fails with the following (16 is the id of the Factory object):
expected 16 
got nil
For some reason it isn't retrieving the value for the object_status_id. If I run through the code in my dev server the object in the database has the object_status_id set properly, so I know the code passes the test. I have multiple instances of this that I can't figure out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a lack of understanding regarding Factory_Girl. I wasn't actually creating the objects in the test database, only in fixtures.